# Case just give me the same date :(

Tags: sql, oracle, case

This CASE only shows me the same date '01 / 01/2999 ', I need to get this date '01 / 01/2999' only when the date is less '01 / 01/1950 '.

If someone can help me, I feel so grateful

```
to_char((
  CASE
    WHEN to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= to_date('01/01/1950','DD/MM/YYYY') 
  THEN
    to_date('01/01/2999','DD/MM/YYYY')
  ELSE
    to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  END) ,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  as FechaEntregaRemesa
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the table (or at least column) definition and sample data and expected results. And your current NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting. I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest it's DD-MON-RR, or at least something with a 2-digit year mask? Which client are you using to run this?

Comment: According to its name `REME_FECHA_ENTREGA` is a **DATE**. So what is `TO_DATE` supposed to do with it? Or are you storing your dates as strings?

Comment: If they were stored as strings - in that format anyway - the query would get the desired result as it is. Converting to date in the case branches and then back to string would still be pointless, of course. I think this is just a (fairly common) misunderstanding of how date formatting works.

Comment: to OP: If someones answer helped you in this thread, please mark it as answered using the Checkmark next to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're doing implicit date conversions, and your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` has a two-digit year, e.g. `'DD/MM/YY'` or this one:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-RR';

-- CTE to generate two dummy values
with RM (REME_FECHA_ENTREGA) as (
  select date '1950-01-01' from dual
  union all select date '1950-01-02' from dual
)
-- your query plus the original date value
select to_char(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA, 'SYYYY-MM-DD') as REME_FECHA_ENTREG,
to_char((
  CASE
    WHEN to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= to_date('01/01/1950','DD/MM/YYYY') 
  THEN
    to_date('01/01/2999','DD/MM/YYYY')
  ELSE
    to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  END) ,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  as FechaEntregaRemesa
from rm;

REME_FECHA_ FECHAENTRE
----------- ----------
 1950-01-01 01/01/2999
 1950-01-02 01/01/2999
```

With a 4-digit format it works as you expect:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

...

REME_FECHA_ FECHAENTRE
----------- ----------
 1950-01-01 01/01/2099
 1950-01-02 02/01/1950
```

When you do

```
to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

you're actually really doing:

```
to_date(to_char(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA, '<NLS_DATE_FORMAT>'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

which is why you see the issue with a 2-digit year model. The implicit `to_char(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA, 'DD-MON-RR')` will give a string like `'01-JAN-50'`. When you pass that string back into `to_date()` with a `YYYY` format model it's interpreted as year 0050, so it's always going to be before 1950.

["Oracle Database converts strings to dates with some flexibility"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079), which is not always helpful... here it isn't complaining that you've supplied two digits for a 4-digit model, or that (in my example) you've passed a month abbreviation instead of a month number. (You can change the behaviour with the FM/FX modifiers, but it's flexible by default.)

You may be tempted to use `alter session` as I did for this demo, but shouldn't rely on NLS settings as you usually have no control over what other users' settings will be. (I suspect you didn't realise you were in this query, but it's still something to watch out for.) Always use explicit conversion and full format models when you have to convert dates to strings and vice versa.

But you don't need to convert your existing date value at all. It's a date, so leave it alone. You can also use date literals for the fixed values to avoid any ambiguity and for a bit less typing:

```
to_char(
  CASE
    WHEN RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA <= date '1950-01-01'
  THEN
    date '2099-01-01'
  ELSE
    RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA
  END,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  as FechaEntregaRemesa

...

REME_FECHA_ FECHAENTRE
----------- ----------
 1950-01-01 01/01/2099
 1950-01-02 02/01/1950
```

or even (modifying @expenguin's suggestion) only using dates when you have to:

```
  CASE
    WHEN RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA <= date '1950-01-01'
  THEN
    '01/01/2099'
  ELSE
    TO_CHAR(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  END as FechaEntregaRemesa
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: so it looks like you don't even need the to_char if your data is already stored as text, and you shouldn't need it for comparing.  Converting to a date is the only thing you should need for comparing the string literal.

**so we take OP's Code:**

```
to_char((
  CASE
    WHEN to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= to_date('01/01/1950','DD/MM/YYYY') 
  THEN
    to_date('01/01/2999','DD/MM/YYYY')
  ELSE
    to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  END) ,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  as FechaEntregaRemesa
```

**And change below**

**IF REME_FECHA_ENTREGA IS A DATE:**

```
  CASE
    WHEN RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA <= date '1950-01-01'
  THEN
    '01/01/2099'
  ELSE
    to_char(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  END as FechaEntregaRemesa
```

**IF REME_FECHA_ENTREGA IS A STRING:**

```
  CASE
    WHEN to_date(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= date '01/01/1950'
  THEN
    '01/01/2999'
  ELSE
    RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA
  END as FechaEntregaRemesa
```

Comment: Doing `to_char('01/01/2999','DD/MM/YYYY')` will throw "ORA-01722: invalid number". You can just use the string literal directly though, why have `to_char()` there at all? If this is an NLS issue then this doesn't change the result though. And why have you added illegal single quotes around the column expression alias? If you wanted a quoted identifier (and you almost certainly don't) then you need double quotes.

Comment: Updated, but I was just trying to help.  My background is in MySQL, so that was my bad.  Looks like your answer may be the correct one.

Comment: I seem to have confused you, sorry; at least if the column data type is DATE, which I'm pretty sure it is. (The OP's code would work if it was a string.) With a date, you do still need the `to_char(RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA, ...)` part, or it will be formatted using the client default. I was just referring to the `'01/01/2099'` literal - *that* doesn't need the `to_char()`.

Comment: Ah I understand.  Why could op use to_date in the initial When statement?  If it's stored as date, wouldn't it already be interpreted as a date?

Comment: Yes it would, and they should not be doing that. It works (sort of - or at least doesn't throw an error) because the date is implicitly converted to a string, before being implicitly converted back to a date. It's the format model being used for that implicit conversion (to a string with a 2-digit year) that's causing the problem.

Comment: I understand now, so he really just needs to change his NLS_DATE_FORMAT to 'dd/mm/yyyy' to solve the issue. I've updated my code to hopefully reflect the correct changes.

Comment: Avoid converting strings to date. `to_date('01/01/1950','DD/MM/YYYY')` can be written as a date literal: `date '1950-01-01'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, does simply defining a date with "date 'yyyy-mm-dd'" actually produce a date?

Comment: @expenguin - [yes it does](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062). Also, referring back to an earlier comment; using `alter session` is a bit of a hack though, it's better not to rely on NLS settings you might not control.

Comment: Alright, so I've made my last set of changes, I believe it should be correct now.  This doesn't address the NLS issue, so would it be up to OP to just change the format of the initial to_date with RM.REME_FECHA_ENTREGA from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'dd/mm/yy'?  Also what if he has dates that overlap? (i.e. 1945, 2045, 2145, etc...)

Comment: On looking at your modified suggestion, I suppose if it's only selecting data you wouldn't need to convert the selection into a date as you'd be pulling a literal string.  Thanks for your help, this was very educational.

Comment: The first of your three code blocks still has the NLS issue (if the column is a date not a string!), but the other two don't, as you're removed the implicit conversion. The second now returns a date rather than a string so that will be displayed using the client NLS settings, but that's a slightly different issue. But yes, that could return strings as well - essentially what the last bit of my answer does. (And possibly what the first version of your answer said!?)

Comment: Just to say, the first code block is ops code untouched. I'll update my post to clarify better.